# Sequelize query returning the wrong number of rows when models are included (findAndCountAll)

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

The following code should return 12 rows (`req.query.limit` = 12). This works fine if I don't include any associated rows, but when I include the related models it returns 7 rows.

I *think* it's down to me using the property `subQuery: false` which allows me (if I remember correctly) to order my results by column correctly - but it's been a long time since I've looked at the ordering code, I'm not very proficient with sequelize, and don't want to break it unnecessarily!

Would really appreciate it if someone can spot where I'm going wrong, and maybe why?

```
exports.getApplications = async(req, res, next) => {
    const index = req.query.index || 0;
    const limit = req.query.limit || 10;
    const order = req.query.orderDirection || 'DESC';
    let orderFields;

    switch(req.query.orderField) {
        case 'lastName': 
            orderFields = [
                ['applicant', 'person', 'lastName'], 
                ['applicant', 'person', 'firstName'], 
 
                ['applicant', 'createdAt', order]

            ];
            break;
        
        default:
            orderFields = [ 'createdAt' ];
        
    }

    try {
        const applications = await Application.findAndCountAll({
            include: [
                {                               
                    model: Job,
                    include: [ 
                        { 
                            model: Company,
                            attributes: [ 'id', 'name' ],
                            include: [
                                {
                                    model: Person,
                                    attributes: [ 'firstName', 'lastName', 'phone', 'email' ]
                                }
                            ]
                        } 
                    ]
                },
                {
                    model: Applicant,
                    include: [ 
                        {
                            model: Person,
                            attributes: [ 'id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'phone', 'createdAt' ]
                        } 
                    ],
                }
            ],

            subQuery: false,

            order: orderFields,      
            limit: parseInt(limit, 10), 
            offset: parseInt(index),
            distinct: true,
            attributes: [ 
                'id',
                'applicantId',
                'jobId',
                [Sequelize.fn('date_format', Sequelize.col('application.createdAt' ), '%d/%m/%y'), 'applicationDate']
 
            ]
        });
        console.log(applications.rows.length); // 7  -- wrong
        console.log(limit);                    // 12 -- correct
        res.status(200).json({msg: 'success', applications: applications});

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
```

Associations:

```
Company.hasMany(Job, { foreignKey: { name: 'companyId', allowNull: false} });
Job.belongsTo(Company, { foreignKey: { name: 'companyId', allowNull: false} });

Person.hasOne(Applicant, { foreignKey: { name: 'personId', allowNull: false, unique: true } });
Applicant.belongsTo(Person, { foreignKey: { name: 'personId', allowNull: false, unique: true } });

Applicant.belongsToMany(Job, { through: Application });
Job.belongsToMany(Applicant, { through: Application });
// Set associations so the Application table can be queried directly
Application.belongsTo(Job, { foreignKey: { name: 'jobId' }});
Application.belongsTo(Applicant, { foreignKey: { name: 'applicantId' } });

Person.belongsToMany(Company, { through: Contact });
Company.belongsToMany(Person, { through: Contact });
```

Comment: Please show model associations

Comment: Hi @Anatoly, I've added them to the OP. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to properly use `findAndCountAll` you need to get rid of `many-to-many` in `include` option OR convert it to `one-to-many` and use `separate: true` option.

**associations**

```js
Company.hasMany(Contact, { foreginKey: 'companyId' });
Contact.belongsTo(Person, { foreginKey: 'personId' });
```

**possible include option**

```js
{ 
  model: Company,
  attributes: [ 'id', 'name' ],
  include: [
    {
      model: Contact,
      separate: true,
      attributes: [],
      include: [{
        model: Person,
        attributes: [ 'firstName', 'lastName', 'phone', 'email' ]
      }]
    }
  ]
}
```

And yes, you will get an **extra level** to get person attributes through `Contact`.

Comment: Hi @Anatoly, thanks for the reply, apologies for not getting back to you sooner - family problems! I don't suppose you could go into *why* a many-to-many relationship can't be used in an include option? Or perhaps a link to an explanation? I'd just like to increase my chances of remembering for next time, and as far as I can see the sequelize docs don't mention it. Thanks again for the helpful reply

Comment: It all goes from how SQL works in case of many-to-many: records would be multiplied. Earlier Sequelize always loaded many-to-many associations using separate queries and now it includes them as qubqueries and it reflects on results when you use `limit` and `offset`

Comment: so I added `Company.hasMany(Contact); Contact.belongsTo(Person);` as you suggested, and then added `Person.hasMany(Contact); Contact.belongsTo(Company);` so that I can use `setCompany()` on the Contact model. It works (as in it adds the contact to the contact table correctly), but I'm getting a `cannot read properties of undefined` error at `lib\associations\has-many.js` :(

Comment: * and it's now returning the correct number of rows, which is nice. But that error is one I've no idea how to fix. The error doesn't seem to come from my code, so I don't know how to fix it

Comment: ah, I think it was the empty attributes array